# Mysql delete trigger no OLD row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want create after delete trigger, the problem is that MySql shows me an error:
`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'attribtue_id' in 'OLD'`, but I have such row. Now I don't know what is wrong.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS delete_price;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_price AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_decimal
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      DECLARE normal_pr decimal(12,4);
      SET @special_pr_attribute_id := 76;
      SET @normal_pr_attribute_id := 75;

      IF (OLD.attribtue_id = @special_pr_attribute_id) THEN
        SET normal_pr := (select `value` from catalog_product_entity_decimal where entity_id=OLD.entity_id AND attribute_id=@normal_pr_attribute_id);
        UPDATE catalog_product_index_price SET price=normal_pr, final_price=normal_pr,min_price=normal_pr,max_price=normal_pr where entity_id=OLD.entity_id;
      ELSEIF (old.attribtue_id = @normal_pr_attribute_id) THEN
        DELETE FROM catalog_product_index_price where entity_id=OLD.entity_id;
      END IF;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try:        attribute_id   
Instead of: attribtue_id
```

Comment: yep this was an answer :D Thanks, now it works perfectly